# Slim: get route inside dynamically created endpoint

Tags: php, slim

How do i get the endpoint route inside a dynamically created endpoint in the slim 2.6 or 3 framework ?

This is the what i have

```
$route = '/endpoint(/:var1(/:var2))';

$app->get( $route, function( $var1="" , $var2="") use( $app, $otherVar ){
    // ideally i would like the contents of $route here for further processing
});
```

Tried with getName() in middelware, however in that scenario i don't have access to the $otherVar...

Any ideas ? i'm open for either slim 2.6 or the new 3

Answer (score 0):

just add **$route** into **use ()**

```
$route = '/endpoint(/:var1(/:var2))';

$app->get( $route, function( $var1="" , $var2="") use ( $app, $route ) {
     // $route is available
});
```

Another solution:

```
$route = '/endpoint(/:var1(/:var2))';

$app->get( $route, function( $var1="" , $var2="") use ( $app ) {
     $route = $app->router()->getCurrentRoute()->getPattern();
});
```

Comment: Yep, both work like a charm, i had tried the first solution, but it failed for some reason, works like charm now, must have been to early in the morning. Cheers.